# matlab cant divide using /

Tags: matlab, if-statement, divide

I have some simple function that takes in a value

This value is the checked off a number of if or elseif statements to calculate another value.

The problem is it seems to find an error when trying to run which says

Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in abc (line 9)
   a = 5000 / g;

the code is as follows

```
function abc(g)


if (g == 100)
   a = 1;
elseif (g <= 99 & g >= 50)    
   a = 200 -2*g;
elseif (g <= 50 & g >= 1)
   a = 5000 / g;
else
  warning('Invalid value passed, a defaults to 1');
  a =1;
end
end
```

So, im passing in abc 100 and i expect a to be 1 but instead it runs through each if / elseif and throws an error on a = 5000/g

I should also mention that i initially tried using && in the elseifs but this also gave an error which said

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in abc (line 6)
elseif (g <= 99 && g >= 50)

Anybody any idea whats going on here ? 
Thanks

Comment: The `g` you're getting as a parameter is a matrix or vector, make sure the caller is giving you a scalar as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably passing a matrix to your function, e.g. when you call

```
abc(yourdata)
```

`yourdata` is actually not one number, but a matrix. If you called directly

```
abc(100)
```

you should not see your problem (or do you?).

In other words, *your main problem is not inside your function*, but when you call it!

Given your description, it seems that you set `yourdata(1)` to the value 100 that you want to test, but some other element of the matrix has a different value, which is why the `if` construct branches into the else case. There, you need `./` instead of `/` if you want to do [element-wise division](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/ldivide.html) instead of [matrix division](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html).

But really you probably just need to make sure that `yourdata` is scalar when you call your function.

Comment: +1 for probably nailing the cause of the bug. Very important in MATLAB to distinguish between the matrix operators `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` and their scalar equivalents `.*`, `./`, etc.

Comment: Yet another argument for parameter checking in even the most trivial of functions.  For Matlab, you should check presence, type, and size are all as expected.